# How to install PIL on Google DataLAB?

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to install PIL using pip on google datalab with the following code:

> %bash pip install pil

and receiving the following error:

> Downloading/unpacking pil   Could not find any downloads that satisfy
>   the requirement pil Cleaning up... No distributions at all found for
>   pil Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: You should `pip install pillow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked in my test environment:

```
%bash
apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev
pip install pillow
```